# Renaming a window which runs a character based application

Tags: forms, cmd, panel, frame

I have an application which starts a character based application and then changes the name of that window. It works, but only until you select a character in that application, at which point the name changes back to the original name. I read that this is normal behavior and there's little you can do about that.
So I thought about embedding this application in my own form/panel, so I can change the name of this form to my liking, but that only seems to work for GUI applications, like notepad.exe.
Does anybody know of a way to run such an application in a panel of how you can create a form around a character based application?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Kind regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself on how to run a cmd window inside a form:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents Tmr As New Timer With {.Interval = 100}
    Private Const HWND_BOTTOM As Integer = &H1
    Private WithEvents proc As New Process
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetParent")>
    Private Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowPos")>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "My title"
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
        proc.Start()
        Tmr.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        If SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle) <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Tmr.Stop()
            SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, New IntPtr(HWND_BOTTOM), 0, 0, Panel1.ClientSize.Width, Panel1.ClientSize.Height, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```